# Some troubles with convergence of random variables in mean, or convergence in $\mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

If we let $\left\lbrace X_n\right\rbrace_{n\geq1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables non negative such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[X]$ then $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$

I have tried to do it with de definition from convergence in $\mathcal{L}^1$:$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]=0$

$$\text{We have that}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[X] \quad\text{so,}\quad \forall\epsilon>0,\exists M\in\mathbb{N}\quad \text{such that }\quad \forall n\geq M\left(\left|\mathbb{E}[X_n]-\mathbb{E}[X]\right|\right)<\epsilon$$
And I wanted to prove that $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists M^{\prime}\in\mathbb{N}\quad \text{such that }\quad \forall n\geq M^{\prime}\left(\mathbb{E}[\left|X_n-X\right|]\right)<\epsilon$

And I thought that if I used triangle inequality it would work but I got the opposite:

$$\begin{aligned}|X_n|-|X|&\leq |Xn-X|\\
\mathbb{E}[|X_n|-|X|]&\leq\mathbb{E}[|Xn-X|]\\
\mathbb{E}[X_n]-E[X]&\leq\mathbb{E}[|Xn-X|]\end{aligned}$$ 
And that will not work.

Comment: It cannot be true. There are many different random variables such that their expectation is the same. However, limit in $\mathcal L^1$ is unique up to the set of measure $0$. So you shouldn't expect that the implication is true (the other way around it is true). Take for example $\Omega = [0,1]$ and let $X_n(t)=n$ for $t \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $X_n(t)=0$ otherwise. Then $\mathbb E[X_n] = 1 \to \mathbb E[X]$ for $X=1$ almost surely, but you can see that $X_n \to 0$ almost surely, so it cannot converge to $1$ in expectation

Comment: Yes, I agree with Dominik, you can also take a normal law with $0$ mean value and a uniform distribution in $[-1,1]$ for example ... they have the same expectation but their $1$-distance is not $0$.

Comment: You are missing an assumption. The statement is true, if you assume $X_n\to X$ in probability. (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheffé%27s_lemma)

Comment: @user251257 I doubt it has something to do with Scheffe lemma. Rather fact that uniform integrability + convergence in probability $\iff$ convergence in expectation. I mean, we would be able to use Scheffe lemma only for subsequence, don't we?

Comment: @DominikKutek: There are many ways to make that statement true...